# ocultar un boton cuando sea iniciado sesion en wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

**Hola amigos es que tengo una duda de como poder ocultar algunos botones cuando en usuario ha iniciado sesión en wordpres que me pueden recomendar agradecería su amable colaboración.**

Comment: Detecta si la sesión se inicio, si se inicio pasale una variable que diga si activar o no el boton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress tiene una función interna encargada para eso, la función es `is_user_logged_in()` que se encarga de verificar si existe una sesión activa, por ende, puedes usarla para mostrar u ocultar información si el usuario esta logueado o no.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo 'El usuario esta logueado';
} else {
echo 'El usuario no esta logueado';
}
```

También puedes hacerlo mediante el rol del usuario, para ello tendrás que usar `wp_get_current_user()` y `current_user_can()`.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if(current_user_can('administrator')) {
echo 'El usuario es administrador';
} else {
echo 'El usuario no esa administrador';
}
```

Esta ultima función verifica si el usuario actual es administrador y muestra un contenido u otro dependiendo de si es o no administrador, puedes usarla para cualquier rol registrado en WordPress.