# Ocultar botón en Wordpress cuando se ha hecho login

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

Necesito ocultar un botón en Wordpress para aquellos usuarios que hayan hecho login, ya que al pulsar en el menú en el botón de login, se redirige y se crea un bucle indeseado al dashboard de Wordpress.

Previamente he intentado reproducir la respuesta de este hilo sin éxito ["ocultar un boton cuando sea iniciado sesion en wordpress"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420989/ocultar-un-boton-cuando-sea-iniciado-sesion-en-wordpress)

Lo ideal sería, que una vez logueado, el botón se convierta en el log out.

En este caso, he intentado realizarlo también por CSS, usando el siguiente código

```
.logged_in .button{display:none;}
```

Aplicado al ID de `menu-item-2300` y crear un menú que incluya el log out a modo de enlace.

La web en concreto es la siguiente [WEB - Activacar](https://activacar.com/)

Comment: [`<p><?php wp_loginout(); ?></p>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_loginout/)

Comment: Finalmente opté por CSS

`.logged-in .log-in{
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
}

.mi-cuenta{
 visibility: hidden;
 display: none;
}
 
.logged-in .mi-cuenta{
 visibility: visible;
 display: block;
}`

Comment: es una opción también ( el mismo `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {`  se usa para establecer la clase )